# How to get mutual groups of two users using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to do something like that:

```
SELECT gid from group_member WHERE uid=<uidA> AND gid IN (SELECT gid from group_member WHERE uid=<uidB>)
```

This should give me all the mutual groups for uidA and uidB.

problem is, I'm using the access_token of uidA to run the query, therefore the inner SELECT
is always empty. There's a way to provide two access tokens?

Comment: I am not sure about two access token, because I never seen this be done. However, why not do this query in two parts?

Comment: I can do it in two parts, but I want make sure I'm doing things the right way.
What about MultiQuery? I think it's classic for this kind of queries, but again I need to provide two access tokens..

Comment: FQL multiqueries do not support passing different access tokens; only [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) do. But you will still need to compare the result of the two queries in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing - two access tokens. You can ask for more permissions and then your `access_token` will allow you to access more facebook data depends on permissions you have.

In your case, you need to ask for two permissions:

- `user_groups`
- `friends_groups`

Then, build your access_token and the FQL query you built will work for you.

You can find the needed permissions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group_member

Comment: I have the right permissions. Maybe it's not working because uidA and uidB are not friends?

Comment: @MichaelAminov, yes, if the users aren't in the list of your friends, this won't work. Just try to run part of this query `SELECT gid from group_member WHERE uid=<uid>` on user who isn't your friend and you will get empty result data.